# How to properly expose boolean search functions when designing a RESTful API?

Tags: api, rest, restful-url

I'm designing a RESTful API for a search function that looks something like this:

`http://example.com/books/?author=John+Smith&title=Brain+Surgery+For+Dummies`

Looking at this URI, I don't immediately know which these two queries the client is performing:

a) all books by John Smith, plus all books entitled "Brain Surgery for Dummies"

b) all editions of "Brain Surgery for Dummies" authored by John Smith.

How might I redesign my URIs to make this more explicit?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from examples "author" is a resource:

```
http://example.com/books/authors/John+Smith
```

OR

```
http://example.com/books/authors/john-smith
```

Search book in the author's books collection

```
http://example.com/books/authors/John+Smith?title=Brain+Surgery+For+Dummies
```

OR

```
http://example.com/books/authors/john-smith?title=Brain+Surgery+For+Dummies
```

Search book in the books collection:

```
http://example.com/books?title=Brain+Surgery+For+Dummies
```

Searching in either case means that exact name/title of the book is not known and search can possibly return multiple items, though particular book by itself is a resource too. In this case you need to define URI for book:

Book resource:

```
http://example.com/books/brain-surgery-for-dummies
```